# Why FIFO is important in camera?

Tags: arduino-uno

I want to buy a camera module for Arduino. I came across this **[OV7670 CMOS Camera Module Lens CMOS 640X480 SCCB W/ I2C Interface Arduino](http://www.ebay.in/itm/M071-OV7670-CMOS-Camera-Module-Lens-CMOS-640X480-SCCB-W-I2C-Interface-Arduino-/111962115189?hash=item1a11764c75:g:KZoAAOSwbwlXB3er)** and **[CMOS With AL422 3M-Bits OV7670 FIFO Camera](http://www.ebay.in/itm/M384-640x480-CMOS-With-AL422-3M-Bits-OV7670-FIFO-Camera-STM32-Chip-Driver-Module-/112230059284?hash=item1a216ecd14:g:QccAAOSwnHZYSPa2)** .

I want to know what difference does FIFO makes in a camera? If I dont use a FIFO will the quality of video be compromised?

Comment: It is all about data transfer mode and performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not FIFO that is the issue, its the FIFO *Buffer* that you need with an Arduino.  The Arduino can't download the data from the camera at the same speed as the camera can send it.  Adding this extra buffer in lets the camera generate the data and the Arduino download it (in the same order that it was generated) at its own pace.

You might not need the FIFO buffer for faster microprocessors, but you do need it for the Arduinos.  You could get your own buffer and rig that up, but for a few extra bucks let them do it for you.